# How to enable the experimental functions of NebulaGraph?

Tags: nebula-graph

I noticed that TOSS in Nebula Graph is an experimental function, how to enable the experimental functions of NebulaGraph?

[image]

Comment: You title says "_How to enable the experimental functions of NebulaGraph?_", but your body says "_I noticed that TOSS in Nebula Graph is an experimental function, how can I use it?_" So are you asking about _any_ experimental feature? Or are you just asking about TOSS? Please make your title and body consistent with one another in what they are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing a parameter in their docs. You can set the `enable_experimental_feature` parameter to true to enable experimental functions of the NebulaGraph database. Doc link: https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/5.configurations-and-logs/1.configurations/3.graph-config/#experimental_configurations

Answer (score 0):

To use the experimental configs in Nebula Graph, you need to set `enable_experimental_feature` to `true` in the `nebula-graphd.conf` file.

Can I ask why you want to use the TOSS feature? It is not recommended that you turn the toss feature on because it is being closed soon.

See this GitHub pull request https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula/pull/5119